# android how to fill up the whole screen with random image views

Tags: android, measure

My purpose is to add multiple random-size small images and fill up the whole screen.
Here is the approach I took.

1. Measure the screen size (width and height)
2. Run a for loop, add a relative layout(row container), get next random image, get the image height and width. Add to the relative layout.
3. Add a new relative layout when the latest image exceed screen width. i.e. new row
4. Stop the for loop when the image exceed screen height.

This can do the job. However, it is very slow to measure view size. It takes few seconds to render above effect.
So I wonder if there is another container or smarter method for above purpose?
Thanks.

Comment: maybe gridview is what you want?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: my images are all in different size, it seems gridview is fixed size for all grid. does anyone has idea? thank a lot!